# I have a Countdown timer in a listView, but is not workig fine

Tags: java, android, listview, countdowntimer

I have a `listView` where each item should display a countdown, the event dates come from Firebase. My countdown timer is working, but only if the list has only one item.

In my fragment I have a `listview`.

In my `adapter_events` I have a text field where I want the counter to appear for each item (textViewTime)

**EventsAdapter.java**:

```
public class EventsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private TextView NomeDoEvento;
    private TextView TempoRestante;
    private TextView DataDoEvento;
    //private TextView DataLocal;

    public EventsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (SharedResources.getInstance().getEventos().size());
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_events, null);

        NomeDoEvento = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewNomeDoEvento);
        TempoRestante = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTempo);
        DataDoEvento = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewDataLocal);

        // Hora Atual
        long currentTimeMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        //Dados do evento
        Evento evento = SharedResources.getInstance().getEventos().get(position);
        NomeDoEvento.setText(evento.getNomeDoEvento());
        //Data do evento
        String[] data = evento.getDataWorld().split("/");
        GregorianCalendar HorarioEvento = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(data[0]) ,Integer.parseInt(data[1])-1,
                Integer.parseInt(data[2]),Integer.parseInt(data[3]),Integer.parseInt(data[4]),0);
        long expiryTime = HorarioEvento.getTimeInMillis() - currentTimeMillis;

        DataDoEvento.setText(HorarioEvento.getTime().toString());

        TempoRestante.setText("");
        new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000; // reminder: 1 sec = 1000 millis
                long minutes = seconds / 60;
                long hours = minutes / 60;
                long days = hours / 24;

                String dayFormat = "d ";
                String hoursFormat = "h ";
                String minutesFormat = "m ";
                String secondFormat = "s";
                String time = days + dayFormat + hours % 24 + hoursFormat + minutes%60 + minutesFormat + seconds % 60 +secondFormat;
                TempoRestante.setText(time);
            }

            // Finished: counted down to 0
            public void onFinish() {
                TempoRestante.setText("Evento iniciado!");
            }
        }.start();

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Fragment.java**:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);

        ListEventos = v.findViewById(R.id.ListView_Eventos);
        Progress = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        Progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DatabaseCommunication.RecuperaEventos(v.getContext());
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: you should clear your timer once your view is recycled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667246/countdown-timer-in-recyclerview-not-working-properly?rq=1

Comment: I'm using a listview because it will not go over about 10 items, in this case, is it reclicated?

Comment: yes i think the items recycled because mobile shows hardly 2,3 items at one time

Comment: My device displays in the current configuration a 6 or 7 items, but append with 2 it already gives error, the stopwatch of the item below normally runs, even that of the item above, does not appear. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Countdown Timer everytime you need a new View to Display. Note that, list view simply recycle the views so for example. If only 10 view will fit in the screen, even if you have a hundred items, only 10 views will be created and your item data will just be binded to that view.

Also note that you are holding on to you `TempoRestante` inside the `CountdownTimer` that will cause a leak.

P.S.
Please name your variables properly and use camel case.

Comment: `TempoRestante`  is updated every second because it is a text view that shows the value of the timer