# Updating TextView in RecyclerView Adapter on Timer without NotifyDatasetChange()

Tags: c#, android, timer

My use case is very simple, I have a `RecyclerView` and each item in `RecyclerView` has a timer which is supposed to run a countdown to 10 seconds (for example) and update the `TextView` in that `ViewHolder` every second to show the time left in seconds.

I created a timer class as following

```
public class BurnTimerTask2
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        private int Secs;
        private TextView tv;
        public BurnTimerTask2(int Secs, TextView tv)
        {
            this.Secs = Secs;
            this.tv = tv;
            t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("PMBurnTimers", "Timer: " + Secs);
            Secs--;
            tv.Text = Secs + " Seconds left";
            if (Secs == 0)
                t.Stop();
        }
    }
```

In my `OnBindViewHolder`, I am calling it like this

```
if (!MYLIST[position].TimerTriggered)
{                                       
  MYLIST[position].TimerTriggered= true;
  new BurnTimerTask2(10, viewHolder.Textview);
}
else
{                   
  viewHolder.Textview.Text = "TIMER ALREADY TRIGGERED";                                      
}
```

The `new BurnTimerTask2(10, viewHolder.Textview);` is where I am calling the timer class and passing the `TextView` (In the above code I am checking if timer has been triggered or not, If it has been triggered, I don't call the timer class so I don't have multiple timers for the same item)

**ISSUES:**

1- `TextView` which shows the seconds does not update unless I scroll the `RecyclerView` slightly, once I slightly scroll the `RecyclerView` it starts ticking and updates text for `TextView` as expected.

2- As soon as Timer class is called, the UI in my `Activity` gets non-responsive, I cannot interact with anything outside the `RecyclerView` for few seconds and when I can it is so slow, if I click a button, it takes forever for the action on that button to trigger. (**Note:** This only happens when I update the `TextView`, If I do not update the `TextView` and run the timer by itself, everything works fine so definalty not the timer which is causing it but updating the `TextView` from the timer causing it)

Obviously I not updating the TextView the right way. I tried the following

1- Run the timer within the adapter (same issues)

2- Create a timer for each item within `ViewHolder` pointed out here [Countdown timer in recyclerview not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667246/countdown-timer-in-recyclerview-not-working-properly) (same issues)

According to the following articles, what I am doing should just simply work but it doesn't
[How to handle multiple countdown timers in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257586/how-to-handle-multiple-countdown-timers-in-recyclerview) and
https://github.com/Manikkumar1988/TimerInRecyclerView

I am not sure how to tackle this issue. Any idea

Comment: You can use a Single Timer in adapter use `notifyItemChange` with payload .

Comment: @ADM how can use a single timer in Adapter if I have all items running a different countdown (10 secs, 20 secs, 30 sec etc) timer?

Comment: A single Timer will Provide call of each second pass . So if you have the start time of each item you can just calculate the Current difference and set it to text view .

Comment: @ADM understood but when I have 3 items visible (for example) and if I am calculating the time difference in `onBindViewHolder` , how do I do that for 3 items at the same time when I only have one instance of timer ticking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: @ADM Getting the visible item in `RecyclerView` is not an issue but I have 3 or 4 items visible at the same time, how do I tackle 1 instance of timer in 4 visible items

Comment: I said you create a Global CountDown timer Which will provide you the second Tick. And inside both variant of bindViewHolder you can calculate the difference between `System.currentTimeInMillies-startTime` . Something like that .  Now you will call `notifyItemChange(position,payload)` from timer `#Tick` method .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230786/discussion-between-ali-and-adm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have an idea using the Chronometer(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer). It is a child of TextView but handles the count and updating View on its own.

The idea is have the viewHolder of your list holds this Chronometer, then in your onBindViewHolder() just make this Chronometer count the correct time (if each item counting a different time).

Try this adapter, I have a separate timer for each item in the list, and onBindViewHolder I will bind that timer into the Chronometer. Try to see if you can replace myTimers[] using your timer class.

```java
public class SOAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SOAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    int timerNumber;
    Chronometer[] myTimers;
    SOAdapter(Context context, int timerNumber){
        this.context = context;
        this.timerNumber = timerNumber;
        this.myTimers = new Chronometer[timerNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < timerNumber; i++){
            Chronometer c = new Chronometer(context);
            c.setTextSize(30);
            c.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            c.start();
            myTimers[i] = c;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SOAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Chronometer timer = new Chronometer(context);
        timer.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        timer.setTextSize(30);
        timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        timer.start();
        return new ViewHolder(timer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SOAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Chronometer cur = myTimers[position];
        holder.bindTimer(cur);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return timerNumber;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Chronometer displayTimer;
        ViewHolder(Chronometer timer) {
            super(timer);
            displayTimer = timer;
        }

        public void bindTimer(Chronometer timer){
            displayTimer.setBase(timer.getBase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good option, let me try :)

Comment: Good idea BUT It seems like `ChronoMeter` only counts up and not down, I need to CountDown

Comment: If you are using API > 24, ChronoMeter support count down "The timer can also count downward towards the base time by setting setCountDown(boolean) to true. " This should solve the display problem, but I guess the hard part is need to update the base correctly during onBindViewHolder()

Comment: yep thanks :) I will accept that as an answer as this was the best solution, I however ended up doing the CountDownTimer as global timer as ADM in above post suggested which also works fine.